# T-SQL Procedure, scalar variable error even after successful updation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
--sp_executesql version
    --SET @SQLQUERY = 'UPDATE @TableName SET Brief = @Brief,
    --               [Full] = @Full,                        
    --               CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,
    --               Department = @Department,
    --               Answer = @Answer WHERE Id=@Id';
 --SET @ParamDefinition=N'@TableName nvarchar(50),@Brief nvarchar(50),@Full nvarchar(MAX),@CreatedBy varchar(256),@Department varchar(256),@Answer nvarchar(MAX),@Id int' 
--  exec sp_executesql @SQLQUERY,@ParamDefinition,@TableName,@Brief,@Full,@CreatedBy,@Department,@Answer,@Id; 

-- exec version
SET @SQLQUERY = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET  
                     Brief ='+ @Brief+',
                     [Full] ='+ @Full+',                        
                     CreatedBy ='+ @CreatedBy+',
                     Department ='+ @Department+',
                     Answer ='+@Answer+' WHERE Id='+CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10))

print @SQLQUERY; 
EXEC (@SQLQUERY)
```

I have used both `EXEC` and `sp_executesql` procedures to execute my dynamic query but both are failing.

In case of `EXEC` the dynamic query is not set to the `@SQLQUERY` variable (seen after debugging), in case of  `sp_executesql` I get scalar variable error though database is updated and I have already passed everything to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case is very simple. You cannot parametrize table/column name in [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement:

```
SET @SQLQUERY = 'UPDATE @TableName       --here is problem
                 SET    Brief = @Brief, 
                        [Full] = @Full,                        
                        CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,
                        Department = @Department,
                        Answer = @Answer 
                 WHERE Id=@Id';


SET @ParamDefinition=N'@TableName nvarchar(50),@Brief nvarchar(50), 
                       @Full nvarchar(MAX), @CreatedBy varchar(256),
                       @Department varchar(256),@Answer nvarchar(MAX),@Id int' 

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @SQLQUERY,@ParamDefinition,
                        @TableName,@Brief,@Full,
                        @CreatedBy,@Department,@Answer,@Id;
```

Use substitution instead:

```
SET @SQLQUERY = N'UPDATE <tab_name> 
                  SET Brief     = @Brief, 
                     [Full]     = @Full,                        
                     CreatedBy  = @CreatedBy,
                     Department = @Department,
                     Answer     = @Answer 
                  WHERE Id = @Id';

SET @SQLQUERY = REPLACE(@SQLQUERY, '<tab_name>', QUOTENAME(@TableName));

SET @ParamDefinition=N'@Brief nvarchar(50),@Full nvarchar(MAX),
                       @CreatedBy varchar(256),@Department varchar(256),
                       @Answer nvarchar(MAX),@Id int';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @SQLQUERY,
                           @ParamDefinition,
                           @Brief,@Full,@CreatedBy, @Department,@Answer,@Id;
```

Notes:

- Table name should have `SYSNAME` datatype.
- It is a good practice to quote identifiers with `QUOTENAME` (to avoid potential SQL Injection attacks).
- I guess `@CreatedBy` is `datetime` that is why I do not understand why it is passed as `varchar(256)`.
- It is a good practice to end every statement with `;`. In future versions this will be mandatory.

Comment: thanks i was stuck on it from a long time past 12 hours precisely :D